# How to replace a pattern in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a sql procedure code. We are migrating the code on different schema. I need to replace all the dimension tables schema.

Example: 
Old schemas: DBO.ABC_DIM, DBO.XYZ_DIM

After replace: MART.ABC_DIM, MART.XYZ_DIM

Could any one let me know how we can do this using regex replace.

Thanks
Sky

Comment: I have some other tables as well like DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD..I do not want to replace DBO here. I just want to replace DBO where it is ending with DIM. [DBO.*_DIM]

Answer (score 1):

You must use:
in the "Find what" field:

```
(DBO)\.
```

and in the "Replace with" field:

```
MART\.
```

Don't forget to place the cursor at beginning of the file. Otherwise the replacements begin after actually cursor position

EDITED:

So in this case if you have others, you can use that:

Find field:

```
\b(DBO\.)(.+?)_DIM\b
```

Replace field:

```
MART\.$2_DIM
```

Some like:

```
DBO.ABC_DIM, DBO.XYZ_DIM, 
DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD
```

become:

```
MART.ABC_DIM, MART.XYZ_DIM, 
DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD
```

**LAST EDIT:**

The above fail with:

```
DBO.ABC_DIM, DBO.XYZ_DIM, 
DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD, DBO.ABC_DIM, DBO.XYZ_DIM, 
DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD, 
DBO.ABC_DIM, DBO.XYZ_DIM,
```

Because in the second row match **DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD, DBO.ABC_DIM**
And **DBO.ABC_DTL** become **MART.ABC_DTL**

**So the right solution is:**

Find field:

```
(DBO\.)(.[^\.]+?)_DIM
```

Replace field:

```
MART\.$2_DIM
```

Comment: I have some other tables as well like DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD..I do not want to replace DBO here. I just want to replace DBO where it is ending with DIM. [DBO.*_DIM]

Answer (score 0):

if you open that schema in VIM, do press `esc` and then

```
:s%/DBO/MART
```

and press enter

`:s` (colon and s) for substitute
   `/DBO`   find DBO
   `/MART`  replace it with MART

once you verify that all the DBOs are replace with MART, you need to save the changes by `esc` and `:wq`

Comment: oh I did not see the OP was asking to replace it in Notepad ++. just realized. Notepad++ should have find and replace option

Comment: I have some other tables as well like DBO.ABC_DTL, DBO.ABC_2_BCD..I do not want to replace DBO here. I just want to replace DBO where it is ending with DIM. [DBO.*_DIM]